# Spark DF: Split array to multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I created spark dataframe using mongodata (in databricks using Python notebook)

[image: Dataframe]

I need to convert this dataframe as

[image: required output]

How can I do this?

Comment: could you add output of .printSchema()? this `sal` column is just a string wirth new lines?

Comment: You can try `pyspark.sql.functions.explode` if `sal` column entries are arrays.

Comment: can you add how do you create dataframe.

Comment: @Mahesh Gupta ``` spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri",constring).load() ```

Comment: @chlebek, yes it's stringtype

Comment: so datatype of salary is array is that correct?

Comment: Thank you @Mahesh, yes...got the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one proposed solution. You can organize your **sal** field into arrays using `$concatArrays` in MongoDB before exporting it to Spark. Then, run something like this

```
#df
#+---+-----+------------------+
#| id|empno|               sal|
#+---+-----+------------------+
#|  1|  101|[1000, 2000, 1500]|
#|  2|  102|      [1000, 1500]|
#|  3|  103|      [2000, 3000]|
#+---+-----+------------------+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_new = df.select('id','empno',F.explode('sal').alias('sal'))

#df_new.show()
#+---+-----+----+
#| id|empno| sal|
#+---+-----+----+
#|  1|  101|1000|
#|  1|  101|2000|
#|  1|  101|1500|
#|  2|  102|1000|
#|  2|  102|1500|
#|  3|  103|2000|
#|  3|  103|3000|
#+---+-----+----+
```